# IIS web.config rewrite rule with POST data to Node.js app

Tags: node.js, post, iis, url-rewriting

I have a Node.js app running on an Azure App Service instance. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config) to create an IIS web.config file that grabs all non-file requests and rewrites to `entry/server.js`, where my app's entry point lives.

For `GET` requests, this works beautifully in all instances.

For `POST` requests, it's another story. While they work in other environments without flaw, `POST` requests only work on IIS when the body is blank. They at least make it to the Node.js application in that scenario. But when I try to send a `POST` request with a body consisting of raw JSON (as you tend to do with Node.js apps), the request never makes it to the Node.js application. After about thirty seconds, it times out and I get a "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."

So, is there something wrong with my web.config file, and the rewrite rule I'm using?

**TLDR: IIS won't send a `POST` request to my Node.JS app if it has a body with raw JSON.**

**EDIT: I am indeed using the bodyParser module, and have posted evidence of that below. It works in environments that are not Azure/IIS**

My web.config file:

```
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
          <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
          <add name="iisnode" path="entry/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
            <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^entry/server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
            </rule>
            <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
            <rule name="StaticContent">
              <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
            </rule>

            <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
              <conditions>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="entry/server.js"/>
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
              <remove segment="bin"/>
            </hiddenSegments>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>

        <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
      </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```

Basic middleware setup for Node.js app:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.WEB_URL,
  credentials: true
}))
```

Comment: Your `web.config` looks alright and is pretty standard for Azure app service app in Node.js. Looks like you have to use the body parser module if you aren't using it already. `const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false}))`

Answer (score 0):

If you use express.js you specifically have to add urlencoded and json for your backend.

```
const app = express()
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({extended:false}),
    express.json(),
)
```

Otherwise POST request and JSON data can't be handled.

If you use something else you have to check in the manual on how to activate POST and JSON data.